# NO ERROR : HTML table rendering in Github pages but not rendering on output

Tags: html, jekyll, github-pages

> I'm pretty new to Jekyll, apologies if it's a basic question

In my [page's preview](https://github.com/xameeramir/xameeramir.github.io/blob/master/_posts/2017-1-16-ienumerable-vs-iqueryable.md), the table is perfectly rendering.

However, in the [resulting page](http://xameeramir.github.io/ienumerable-vs-iqueryable/), it doesn't.

THERE IS NO ERROR IN THE CODE AS SEEN ON GITHUB PAGES BECAUSE THE REPOSITORY IS COMPILING SUCCESSFULLY.
What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Github.com is just rendering your post (and generally markdown file) with no layout from your jekyll and thus with none of your style sheets.

On the other side http://xameeramir.github.io/ienumerable-vs-iqueryable/ is your github pages generated jekyll using your layouts and thus, your css.

Answer (score 0):

The table has a lot of html elements that makes the markdown (or kramdown) processor confused.

Try using the correct table syntax to generate them: https://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#tables

For example, the following:

```
| Header1 | Header2 | Header3 |
|:--------|:-------:|--------:| 
| cell1 | cell2 | cell3 | 
| cell4 | cell5 | cell6 |
|---- 
| cell1 | cell2 | cell3 | 
| cell4 | cell5 | cell6 | 
|===== 
| Foot1 | Foot2 | Foot3 
{: rules="groups"}
```

Will end up looking as:

```
<table rules="groups"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
<th style="text-align: left">Header1</th> 
<th style="text-align: center">Header2</th> 
<th style="text-align: right">Header3</th>
 </tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
<td style="text-align: left">cell1</td> 
<td style="text-align: center">cell2</td> 
<td style="text-align: right">cell3</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td style="text-align: left">cell4</td> 
<td style="text-align: center">cell5</td> 
<td style="text-align: right">cell6</td> 
</tr> 
</tbody> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
<td style="text-align: left">cell1</td> 
<td style="text-align: center">cell2</td> 
<td style="text-align: right">cell3</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td style="text-align: left">cell4</td> 
<td style="text-align: center">cell5</td> 
<td style="text-align: right">cell6</td> </tr> 
</tbody> 
<tfoot> 
<tr> 
<td style="text-align: left">Foot1</td> 
<td style="text-align: center">Foot2</td> 
<td style="text-align: right">Foot3</td> 
</tr> 
</tfoot> 
</table>
```